Can a submitted DS160 form be amended?
The answer at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/188863/82655 says:

For those in the UK, the US embassy's official link clearly states that you can amend your DS160 and bring the updated version to the embassy without needing to book a new appointment.

Can a submitted DS160 really be amended? If so, how?
After submitting DS160 form I cannot find any method to amend the form. If you know a way to amend a submitted DS160 form, please share how. If there is no way to amend the form, what does that quoted answer mean?
